# Problems after upgrading Ubuntu 9.04 to 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, installation

Yesterday, I installed ubuntu version 9.04 using wubi.  It is working fine, but today it asks to upgrade to 9.10 and I follow the instructions.  I upgraded successfully, and it asks to restart the system.  When I restarted the system, it is showing DOS like window with some error.  How can I solve this issue, because it is not starting?

I installed both windows and ubuntu.

Comment: I'm guessing this is the problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/477104?comments=all

Answer (score 1):

> Yesterday, I installed ubuntu version 9.04 using wubi.

If you just installed 9.04, why not try the newest version 10.10? You can download it [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/10.10/). A fresh install is better than an upgrade. If you really want [9.10](http://releases.ubuntu.com/9.10/), do a fresh install instead of an upgrade. You should only consider an upgrade if you had data and programs installed you didn't want to lose/transfer.